# JQuery line is breaking my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox

So I'm working on a little bit of jQuery for a site I'm working on and for some reason when I put single quotes inside double quotes Firefox, in it's eternal glory, changes them to double quotes thus breaking my code.

I even tried putting it in an external javascript file even though I'm just prototyping at this point. No good. Wouldn't load the file!

```
$("#clips").after("<ul id='slideshow-nav'><li><a id='gallery-next' href='#' title='View the next piece'>Next</a></li><li><a id='gallery-prev' href='#' title='View the previous piece'>Prev</a></li></ul>");
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered:-

```
$("#clips").after('<ul id="slideshow-nav"><li><a id="gallery-next" href="#" title="View the next piece">Next</a></li><li><a id="gallery-prev" href="#" title="View the previous piece">Prev</a></li></ul>')
```

?

Whilst its quite normal to have ' and " usage interchangable in Javascript usage of ' to delimit attribute values in HTML / XML is rare.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching the single and double quotes?

```
$("#clips").after('<ul id="slideshow-nav"><li><a id="gallery-next" href="#" title="View the next piece">Next</a></li><li><a id="gallery-prev" href="#" title="View the previous piece">Prev</a></li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error in FF3.5.

```
<div id="clips">test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#clips").after("<ul id='slideshow-nav'><li><a id='gallery-next' href='#' title='View the next piece'>Next</a></li><li><a id='gallery-prev' href='#' title='View the previous piece'>Prev</a></li></ul>");
</script>
```

gives me:

```
<div id="clips">test</div>
<ul id="slideshow-nav">
  <li><a title="View the next piece" href="#" id="gallery-next">Next</a></li>
  <li><a title="View the previous piece" href="#" id="gallery-prev">Prev</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in FF 3.5.2.  Are you wrapping it in $(function() { }); to make sure that the DOM is loaded?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>tt</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $("#clips").after("<ul id='slideshow-nav'><li><a id='gallery-next' href='#' title='View the next piece'>Next</a></li><li><a id='gallery-prev' href='#' title='View the previous piece'>Prev</a></li></ul>");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='clips'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. A few things to try:

Restructure for readability (is same code, using an array with a .join('') on the end):

```
$("#clips")
.after( [
   "<ul id='slideshow-nav'>",
       "<li><a id='gallery-next' href='#' title='Next piece'>Next</a></li>",
       "<li><a id='gallery-prev' href='#' title='Previous piece'>Prev</a></li>",
   "</ul>"
].join('')
);
```

Rename ids just to make sure there are no conflicts on the page (often has odd errors):

```
$("#clips")
.after( [
   "<ul id='slideshow-nav2'>",
       "<li><a id='gallery-next2' href='#' title='Next piece'>Next</a></li>",
       "<li><a id='gallery-prev2' href='#' title='Previous piece'>Prev</a></li>",
   "</ul>"
].join('')
);
```

Use all double quotes with escape characters:

```
$("#clips")
.after( [
   "<ul id=\"slideshow-nav2\">",
       "<li><a id=\"gallery-next2\" href=\"#\" title=\"Next piece\">Next</a></li>",
       "<li><a id=\"gallery-prev2\" href=\"#\" title=\"Previous piece\">Prev</a></li>",
   "</ul>"
].join('')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is working for me?

http://pastebay.com/51896

Answer (score 0):

Both single and double quotes are valid in JavaScript and HTML:

> HTML:
> "[Double style quotes are the most common, but single style quotes are also allowed.](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_attributes.asp)"
>
> JavaScript:
> "[A string literal is zero or more characters enclosed in single or double quotes.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecma-international.org%2Fpublications%2Ffiles%2FECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN%2FECMA-262%2C%25202nd%2520edition%2C%2520August%25201998.pdf&ei=e4ahSvz8B9GNsAbjyLDSBA&usg=AFQjCNHHMRH8zEWdchy9MjnbdyM850nh9Q)"